# Is there a Jade template syntax checker/validator?

Tags: syntax-error, pug

I have some syntax errors in my Jade templates. Are there any tools that can help me debug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found it. Use `jade [fileName].jade` to debug your Jade template.

You can install the Jade tool with `npm install jade --global`.

Comment: fantastic! got me out of a bind in a hurry :)

Comment: It looks like this can still throw errors, like when you use a variable in a template that is only defined in your code. Additionally, if you are doing a syntax check against a file that "extends" another file, jade might report the wrong file's context (if file A extends file B, and file B has an error, jade will report the error as existing in file A).

Comment: For those that still need some direction here, do `sudo npm install jade --global` on your command line.

Comment: Thanks @Ergin for the tip. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this here because I still had to google.

npm i -g pug-lint

NOTE: jade has changed its name to pug

Answer (score 0):

web storm is a better tool for jade development ,it idents and corrects jade files