# Weird Node js error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not much familiar with node js, but I was forced to use node js to launch on heroku.

It all went smoothly, probably until a few days ago, but I didn't know why but it suddenly gives this much error.

```
Error: /app/index.jade:9
  7| meta(name='viewport', content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1')
  8| link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css', media='screen')
> 9| link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/jquery-ui.css', media='screen')   
 10| link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/jquery.pnotify.default.css', media='screen')
 11| link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/jquery.pnotify.default.icons.css', media='screen')
 12| link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/app.css', media='screen') 

 unexpected text at Object.Lexer.fail (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:804:11)
 at Object.Lexer.next (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:863:15)
 at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:113:46)
 at Parser.lookahead (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:111:23)
 at Parser.peek (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:88:17)
 at Parser.tag (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:704:22)
 at Parser.parseTag (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:690:17)
 at Parser.parseExpr (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:199:21)
 at Parser.block (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:660:25)
 at Parser.tag (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:777:26)
```

This is What my index.jade is about

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content='yes')
    meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content='black')
    meta(name='viewport', content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css', media='screen')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/jquery-ui.css', media='screen')  
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/jquery.pnotify.default.css', media='screen')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/jquery.pnotify.default.icons.css', media='screen')
```

Any suggestion why it becomes wrong?

Comment: Please use the code tag wrapper.  It's the little curly braces over the editor box.  It's very difficult to read your output.

Comment: [Is there a Jade template syntax checker/validator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173144/is-there-a-jade-template-syntax-checker-validator)

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: You're using relative **and** absolute paths to link your stylesheets although the locations seem to be the same. Did you check on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Jade to

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content='yes')
    meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content='black')
    meta(name='viewport', content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css', media='screen')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css', media='screen')  
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/jquery.pnotify.default.css', media='screen')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/jquery.pnotify.default.icons.css', media='screen')
```

As @Max Leske said in the comments, you are mixing relative and absolute paths.

Not sure why that would be causing an issue, but it's more than a coincidence I feel.

Incidently, the reason I asked to see your `package.json` is because recently there was an update to Jade on NPM that has caused the issue you are reporting:

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1347

If you have something like:

```
"jade" : "*"
```

in your `package.json` that will basically mean "install the latest version"

So, every time you push to heroku, it will update your version of jade to the latest version, thus introducing any breaking changes.
I suspect this is what happened a few days ago, causing this bug (you pushed to heroku, forcing an update of jade to the latest version)

It would be better to specify version numbers in your `package.json` file to avoid this.

Comment: Changing to relative path doesn't work for me, however, I have tried to use 0.35.0 for jade and it works. Thanks!